# how put html+script inside the image.php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, function

I'm unable to combine these codes

put this **html code**

```
 <div id="time"></div>
    <script>

    function Timer() {
       var dt=new Date()
       document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=dt.getHours()+":"+dt.getMinutes()+":"+dt.getSeconds();
       setTimeout("Timer()",1000);
    }
    Timer();
    </script>
```

**inside image.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
$str1= " $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"; 
$str2= "**place code html**"; 
$image= imagecreate(200,40); 
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255); 
$color= imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0); 
imagefill($image,0,0,$background); 
imagestring($image,10,5,5,$str1,$color); 
imagestring($image,10,5,20,$str2,$color); 
imagepng($image)
?>
```

**Output expect**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbEW1.png)

Comment: From your expected output image I can only guess you want to create a dynamic image that display and IP address and time? to combine javascript with `PHP` you would need to send the output of the `javascript` to `php` as `php` runs on the server before any client-side languages such as `javascript`

Comment: about yes ,can you help me?

Comment: Why not research a way to get the clients timezone/time stamp using php? This would save trying to combine javascript to post to php to then create the image?

Comment: your think is good but i want to show time user pc /                                                  code php user pc timezone?

Answer (score 0):

use `include()` or `require()`. It can load html file in php

e.g.

index.html :

```
<div class="node">hello, world!</div>
```

include.php

```
<?php
    include("index.php");
?>
```

result in include.php :

```
hello, world!
```

---

It will be working

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
$str1= " $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"; 
$str2= "**place code html**"; 
$image= imagecreate(200,40); 
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255); 
$color= imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0); 
imagefill($image,0,0,$background); 
imagestring($image,10,5,5,$str1,$color); 
imagestring($image,10,5,20,$str2,$color); 
imagepng($image)
include("image.html")
?>
```